# Missing inertia for hokuyo model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I just modeled our heterogeneous multi-robot swarm in gazebo.
Some of them are equipped with the hokuyo sensor form your supported models folder.
I mentioned, that the  section is missing, which is awe full if you have robots in the size of such a sensor.
In the WWW I just found rough guesses for the URG04-LX sensor, but it would be nice to have a model which has the exact inertia, so that we can model our upcoming multi-robot experiments.

Additional, I think it is very sloppy in gazebo to set the initial values of inertia to <1 1 1>, <0 0 0> would be better from my point of view.

Can someone support such a inertia model?

Kind regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7958/missing-inertia-for-hokuyo-model/) by [tik0](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1100/tik0/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can submit a pull request change a model via the [gazebo_model repository](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models). Contributions are always welcome.

There is also a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_contrib&cat=build_robot).

If you want to suggest a change to the default inertia value, please make a pull request to [sdformat](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1